# How to install wine on Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 32-bit?

Tags: apt, kali-linux, wine

I am trying from last few hours, I want to install wine on kali rolling.

My source.list has only 1 entry:

deb http://http.kali.org /kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

I tried every possible ways following by kali fourms, and others websites, but not success till now.

Few looks on my tries:

```
apt-get install wine
dpkg --add-architecture i386 
apt-get update
apt-get install wine-bin:i386
```

Error I get from the last command:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wine-bin:i386
```

Can anyone help me to successfully  install `wine` on rolling?

I am using 32bit, fresh install of kali.

I also tried again after performing an update:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.tecmint.com/install-wine-in-linux/, it worked for me.

On Debian systems, you should follow below instructions to install latest WineHQ development builds.

First, enable 32-bit packages, then download and install key which is used to sign packages.

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
$ sudo apt-key add Release.key
```

Next place the repository to */etc/apt/sources.list* file with the following content at the bottom:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ DISTRO main
```

Note: Don’t forget replace *DISTRO* with your Debian release either *wheezy*, *jessie*, *stretch* or *sid*.

Debian Wheezy users also need to add the following line to */etc/apt/sources.list* file to avoid any issues with missing software dependencies.

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main
```

Now update the package repository database and install WineH! development branch as shown.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install winehq-devel
```

For other Linux distributions, the installation instructions can be found at https://www.winehq.org/download.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install wine32
```

Even if the second command gives you an error, try again. For example `couldn't find the repository`. Just try again and again and check your connection.