# How to install AutoCAD in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, wine

I try to installing **AutoCAD** on my Kali, but I can't find a linux version for **AutoCAD**, so I tried installing **wine** with these; `sudo apt-get install wine-bin:i386`, `sudo apt-get install wine32`, but it keeps prompting me these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wine-bin:i386
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine32 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or 
is only available from another source
E: Package 'wine32' has no installation candidate
```

I then tried to check if I already have **wine** installed and the version using `wine --version`, it then prompted me:

```
it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it.
as root, please execute "apt-get install wine32"
wine-1.8.7 (Debian 1.8.7-2)
```

Any solution please?

Comment: Have you tried to run `apt-get update` ?

Comment: Yeah I have ran all my update. @DevilaN

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289780/how-to-install-wine-on-kali-kali-gnu-linux-rolling-32-bit

And change title - you are having currently problems with wine, not with AutoCAD

Comment: U mm I don't really think so, the major thing is the AutoCAD not even the wine. I only thought of installing wine to see if I could install the windows file of the AutoCAD, but even on that the wine won't still install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use AutoCAD or Wine you should install another distro.  Kali is a specific Linux distro aimed at pentesting, and it is unlikely that it would have a package for Wine. As [its official documentation says](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux):

> Kali Linux is specifically geared to meet the requirements of professional penetration testing and security auditing. To achieve this, several core changes have been implemented in Kali Linux which reflect these needs:
>
> (...)
>
> A minimal and trusted set of repositories: given the aims and goals of Kali Linux, maintaining the integrity of the system as a whole is absolutely key. With that goal in mind, the set of upstream software sources which Kali uses is kept to an absolute minimum. Many new Kali users are tempted to add additional repositories to their sources.list, but doing so runs a very serious risk of breaking your Kali Linux installation.